# Is it possible to express $f(q,p)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{n}(q)\beta_{n}(p) \ $?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose we have a function $f:U\subset {\rm I\!R}^{2} \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$ with as many derivatives as we want. I'll write $(q,p) \in U$.

I read a result on Quantum Mechanics where the author said he could write this function as:

$$f(q,p)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{n}(q)\beta_{n}(p),$$

for some set of functions $\{\alpha_{n}\}$, $\{\beta_{n}\}$.

Is it true?

I thought a possible argument is that we use exactly this form of function in the method of separation of variables used to solve linear PDEs. However, I do not know if this argument really holds.

Thank you, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's difficult to swallow this for an arbitrary $U\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ the [Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem (see "Applications") easily gives it when $U=[a,b]\times[c,d]$, and in similar cases.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It helped me.